# wazuh agents cannot connect using cloudflare tunnel

Tags: docker, tcp, tunnel, cloudflare

I installed [wazuh](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/deployment-options/docker/wazuh-container.html#change-pwd-existing-usr) in docker on my synology which exposes the following ports:

```
0.0.0.0:1514-1515->1514-1515/tcp, :::1514-1515->1514-1515/tcp
```

On the same machine (also in docker) i am running a cloudflare tunnel.
This is my configuration:

[image]

The connection via https to the dashboard works as expected.

Sadly my clients are not able to connect via tcp.

Testing the connection from any client does not work:

```
"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond <some-generic-ip>:1514`
```